# Como tirar "/" do final de uma pasta do servidor?

Tags: htaccess

É o seguinte: tenho uma pasta de contato no meu site, que aparece assim: www.meusite.com/contato/ , e como eu faço para ela aparecer www.meusite.com/contato ?
Mas tem que ser só por pasta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    DirectorySlash off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Lembrando que você terá que ter o módulo [mod_rewrite](http://gustavodutra.com/geek/como-usar-mod_rewrite-de-verdade/) habilitado no Apache.

---

#### Observação importante:

Não é uma boa ideia linkar o diretório de um website sem o último `/`.

- Porque é semanticamente incorreto ao induzir que o link deveria ser um arquivo sem extensão ao invés de um diretório:
  www.meusite.com/contato/ : diretório
  www.meusite.com/contato : arquivo
- Ocorre um redirecionamento de www.meusite.com/contato para www.meusite.com/contato**/**, quando o servidor perceber que se trata do diretório "contato".
- Pode ocorrer erro 404 no servidor.

Mais detalhes em [Linking Issues: Why a Trailing Slash in the URL Does Matter](http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/thou-must-not-steal-the-trailing-slash-from-my-urls/#why-stealing-slashes-is-plain-robbery).

Comment: Teria como elaborar o 1o tópico (mera curiosidade, queria apenas entender seu ponto de vista) "é semanticamente incorreto ao induzir que o link deveria ser um arquivo sem extensão ao invés de um diretório" Concordo 100% com a adição (ou subtração) automática ser um erro (afinal com ou sem barra são URLs "100% diferentes"). Mas qual seria o problema real se, por exemplo, um site todo atendesse só URLs sem barra no fim, por exemplo?

Comment: PS: Não é uma contestação, é mera curiosidade. E quando falo de elaborar, digo só um comentário mesmo. A resposta principal já ta OK no meu ver.